# Align table content to header

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, sectioning, header-footer

I think because I do not use a frame in this table, the section header is not aligned with the table content. Is there any solution to this?

```
\section{Bildung}

\begin{tabular}{p{3.3cm} l  l}
\bf 2000-2004 & content \\
[0.2cm]
\bf 2004-2013 & content \\
[0.2cm]
\bf Seit 2016 & content
\end{tabular}
```

[image: example]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! This section is not numbered?

Comment: You can write `\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}p{3.3cm}ll}`. Note that `\bf` has been obsolete for  about 25 years. Use `\bfseries` instead.

Comment: Just  a question: do you need 3 columns in your real document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this:

[image]

for this you need to remove the first `\tabcolsep` with `@{}` in the first table column:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\section*{Bildung}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\bfseries}p{3.3cm} l  }
2000-2004 & content \\
2004-2013 & content \\
Seit 2016 & content
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```